# Struggling to remove whitespace when on mobile

Tags: html, forms, responsive

I am working on a page that responds to screen size so that it looks teh same on desktop and mobile devices, but i am struggling to remove the extra white space at the top and bottom of my page. I dont want to change the css because i only want it to be removed when on mobile devices.

Is there a way for me to remove the extra white space without effecting the desktop view ?

Comment: use media query in your css, and make sure the whitespace is something set through css (padding/margin/height/width), not something set through multiple space/tab/line break/```<br>```/```&nbsp;```

Comment: Ahh that seems like it should work :D Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use min-max width, always design for mobile first.

Answer (score 0):

Exemple

```
/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* For desktop: */
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
```

Comment: why do you answer it twice? better you edit your answer before.